# There is error while uploading csv file in play console. How to avoid it?

Tags: google-play-console

[image: Getting error while uploading csv file in google play console]

invalid row(s) in the CSV file: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ..etc

Answer (score 0):

Your format is incorrect should make like this:

[image]

As in picture you only can add email address in one column with multiple rows